# How to prove the idempotence of consequence operator?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-languages

Given language $\mathcal{L}$, $A$ is a set of formulas in $\mathcal{L}$, $\alpha$ is a formula in $\mathcal{L}$, $Th(A)\overset{\text{def}}{=}\{\alpha \in \mathcal{L} \mid A \models \alpha\}$. Here [cs491](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/%7Emjs/teaching/KnowledgeRep491/Prelim_ConseqRels_491-2x1.pdf) the paper states Th(A) has a property that $Th(Th(A))=Th(A)$. However, I don't get the proof of this property. I have tried to prove this equality by mutual subset but failed. Any ideas on this are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*

$\alpha \in \text {Th}(\text {Th}(A))$ means that $\text {Th}(A) \vDash \alpha$.

This means that every model of $\text {Th}(A)$ is a model of $\alpha$.

By definition of $\text {Th}(A)$, every model of $A$ is a model of $\text {Th}(A)$.

Thus, every model of $A$ is a model of $\alpha$, i.e. $A \vDash \alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But I still have questions on **By definition of Th(A), every model of A is a model of Th(A).** Why is that? To prove **every model of A is a model of Th(A)**, we have to prove $\forall M \models A, M \models Th(A)$, that is $\forall M$, if all the formulas in A evaluate to be true in M, then all the formulas in Th(A) evaluate to be true in M, since $A \subseteq Th(A)$, then how can we prove all formulas in $Th(A) \setminus A$ evalutes to be true under M by "definition of Th(A)"? If this can be proved I think I can understand.

Comment: @BobHU - Because Th(A) is the set of formulas that are consequence of $A$, i.e. that are true in every model of $A$.